# How boundary pixels are treated in matchTemplate() in openCV?

Tags: opencv

I am trying to do the correlation between two images (smaller image with a bigger image). How are the boundary treatment done in openCv?

```
cv::matchTemplate(webcamImageReceived,templateImage,resultImage,CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template never cross image boundary, and result image have size reduced by template size (half template size from each image side).

Look here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

(take a look at:

```
  /// Create the result matrix
  int result_cols =  img.cols - templ.cols + 1;
  int result_rows = img.rows - templ.rows + 1;
```

)

Comment: Thank you but i had seen it before. My doubt is, when the template image is the the (0,0) position of the given image, at that time do we have to do padding for the given image? For example, the link you sent me above, in that link under the heading "how does it work"...see the second image where the template image is placed on the given image but not completly...in such a situation how does opencv manages correlation?

Comment: The second image is scaled fragment of source image (just for illustration). There is only one image they process in tutorial. But you can use copyMakeborder for control border behavior. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/copyMakeBorder/copyMakeBorder.html

Comment: Under the section "How does it work?"and below the line "To identify the matching area, we have to compare the template image against the source image by sliding it:"....they have placed the `template image` over the `source image` to start sliding it. My question is, in that particular scenario...what is done my cv::matchTemplate()?...i don't want to control the boundary treatment, just want to know how matchTemplate() does it?

Comment: It set ROI on source image (upper left corner to position (i,j), width and height equals to width and height of template). Uses correlation equations (you select by flags) for compute result. Put the result to position (i,j) of result image. Increments position. And repeat from the beginning. When it reaches source.cols - template.cols it increments i , when it reaches (source.rows - template rows,source.cols - template.cols) , it finishes the processing.